# Proof using the Handshake Theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected simple graph with all vertices with even degree. How can I prove that $G$ has no bridges using the handshake theorem?

Can anyone give me a hint about the proof of this?
And why the graph $G$ can have cutting vertices?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $G$ has a bridge: an edge $vw$ such that $G-vw$ is disconnected.

Then $G-vw$ must have exactly two components: one containing $v$ and one containing $w$. What are the vertex degrees like in, for example, the component containing $v$?

---

To find a graph with cut vertices and no odd degrees, just try a few examples. The [butterfly graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_graph) is the smallest.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:  Have you seen the proof that your graph $G$ must have an Eulerian cycle?  This is very similar.